# SQL Reporting Services maximum subscribers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription

I'm just wondering if anyone has had any problems having too many subscribers for a report in reporting services. I had 11 people in the "to" address and the 11th person never received anything. On one of the reports I moved the 11th name to the "cc" field and they occasionally received it, but on another report with the same parameters etc they don't receive anything. Is there some sort of limit to 10 recipients?

Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't find this question SQL-related. Retag it or be more specific (probably you meant some particular software for subscription).

Comment: @samuil: it's is SSRS/SQL related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there is a limit to how many email addresses you can fit on one line.

It's a simple character string limit and it applies to the SMTP usage rather than SSRS itself.

Edit: I can't confirm this last sentence. It could be as SSRS limit. COuld be "255", which nicely fits 10 addresses [according to this](http://www.eph.co.uk/resources/email-address-length-faq/#emailmaxlength)...

You'd normally use a distribution list so that you manage the user list in, say,  Exchange/Outlook rather than in the SSRS subscription.